# How to get C compiler #error if a sizeof(struct ...) not equal to a given number?

Tags: c++, c, compiler-errors, compilation, sizeof

How to get C compile time #error if a sizeof(struct ...) not equal to a given number?

The question is from programming course, where I'd like to avoid to run miss-sized binary code.

(The sizeof operator, as we know, doesn't work in #if .. #endif directive.)

Answer (score 5):

> How to get C compile time #error if a sizeof(struct ...) not equal to a given number?

You cannot, because the pre-processor knows nothing about sizes of types.

You can however `static_assert`:

```
static_assert(sizeof(T) == N, "T must have size N")
```

In C, the keyword is `_Static_assert`, also available through macro `static_assert` in `<assert.h>`.

Answer (score 4):

Don't. You already explained why.

In modern C++ you can write:

```
static_assert(sizeof(T) == 42);
```

Although it is better to write code that doesn't *care* what the size of `T` is.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <assert.h>
//T should have size 10
static_assert(sizeof(T) == 10)
```

It's available only the latest C compiler

Comment: Detail: `_Static_assert` available since C11.  Latest C is [C18](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C18_(C_standard_revision))